How to calculate estimate gas fee using wagmi for the swap
I need to calculate estimate gas fee for the swap function using wagmi
import { useEstimateGas } from 'wagmi'
import { parseEther } from 'viem'
import { config } from './config'

function App() {
  const result = useEstimateGas({
    account: '0xA0Cf798816D4b9b9866b5330EEa46a18382f251e', 
    to: '0xd2135CfB216b74109775236E36d4b433F1DF507B',
    value: parseEther('0.01'),
  })
}

I tried with this hook , but using this unable to fetch the estimate gas fee for the swap function.

In Wagmi2.0, can estimateGas before writeContract.
Note following URL.
https://wagmi.sh/core/api/actions/estimateGas
